# Waking From Sleep

Tags: sleep

Often it happens that I cannot wake my computer from sleep, it just does not react and I must force restart.

In power management is set to put display to sleep after 15 minutes and computer never.

So I guess it cannot wake display from sleep.

Does this happen to anyone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste the following in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen 'true'
```

We have had this issue several times and it seems to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the other way around? put the computer to sleep and not the screen? Secondly, may be you have lock problem, go to configuration editor. desktop, gnome, lockdown and enable disable_lock_screen.

Comment: Will try that, thanks. But this looks like a buggy behaviour anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me too, I solved it by downgrading my BIOS firmware, works perfectly now. Go on your model's support page and try several firmwares, see if they fix the problem.